# Cannot access the volumes from EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 2 volumes attached to an EC2 instace. One to /dev/sda1 and one to xvdf
When I run this command, I get an error :

```
ubuntu@ip-10-6-206-254:~$ ls -l /dev/sd* /dev/xv*
ls: cannot access /dev/sd*: No such file or directory
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202,  0 Jan 19 13:59 /dev/xvda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202,  1 Jan 19 13:59 /dev/xvda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 202, 80 Jan 19 13:59 /dev/xvdf
```

How can I access the volume on /dev/sda1 (root device)?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From AWS EC2 User Guide:

> Depending on the block device driver of the kernel, the device might
>   be attached with a different name than what you specify.
>
> For example, if you specify a device name of **/dev/sdh**, your device
>   might be renamed **/dev/xvdh** or **/dev/hdh** by the kernel; in most cases,
>   the trailing letter remains the same.

The device `/dev/sda1` is attached to the instance as `/dev/xvda1`.

Refer [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html) for more information on device naming

Comment: Thank you. How can I browse the files in that volume ?

Comment: `df -h` command should give you the mount points of these devices which is actually a directory path. You can use `cd` to navigate through the directories, if you have access.

Comment: You saved me !!

Comment: Glad that it helped.